# google app engine java jpa one to many remove

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

In Google App engine java jpa one to many relation, how do i remove the child elements.
For example

```
Class Parent{
   // key defined here

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
   private List<Child> childs = null;
.
.
.
}

Class child{
//key defined here too
@ManyToOne
private Parent parent;
.
.
.
}
```

I created

```
Parent parent=new Parent()
parent.getChilds().add(new Child(1));
parent.getChilds().add(new Child(2));
//save parent 
.
.
```

and now i want to remove both the childs 1 and 2 and add a new child 3

```
Parent p=//getParent
p.setChilds(new ArrayList<Child>())//remove all older childs
parent.getChilds().add(new Child(3));//adding new child 3
.
.
```

But when i again fetch the same parent i have all the 3 childs but not only child 3.

Can any one please guide me.

Thanks,
Ramesh.V

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do

```
parent.getChilds().clear();
```

since that saves deleting and recreating a List, and may have the added benefit of working around some GAE issue. PS. the plural of "child" is "children"!

Comment: Sorry not working... but clearing or setting a new empty object both are some made no difference in working...

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the relationship from the owning side - in this case Child#parent. So for each child in parent collection try either: removing the child element or setting the parent element to null. Something like:

```
Parent p = //getParent
List<Child> children = p.getChildren();
for (Child c : children) {
    c.setParent(null);
}

children.clear();
children.add(new Child(3));
```